# Create a PHP Form to load URL

Tags: php, html, forms

I want my form to load webpages. I want to turn html textbox into address bar. Just like whenever I write URL into that, It loads webpages in the same window.
My current HTML code is:

```
<html>
<body>
<title>BlogSoc Browser</title>
<h1 style="font-family:verdana;font-size:50px;color:#000000;text-align:center;">Address Bar</h1>
<center><form method="GET" action="/load.php"><input type="text" name="url" value="http://" /><input type="submit" value="Go" name="submit" /></form></center>
</body>
</html>
```

It looks like this: (couldn't post image)
or you can just open http://blogsoc.org/load
Please tell me the appropriate load.php code. Thanks in advance.

Comment: After submit form you want to redirect page according to url or open url page in your load.php. Please tell what you want?

Comment: Do you want the site designated by the url to be displayed INSIDE the current page? because then you'll want to look up iframes.

Comment: No. I want to simply turn that html textbox into address bar. So that whenever I write any URL in text box, It opens the webpage. Solved by @Akhilesh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using client side scripting:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#myform').submit(function(){ //when form is submitted..
            window.location = $('#url').val(); //..get url from the textbox and load that url
            return false; // prevent the form from being submitted
        });
    });
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <form id="myform">
    <input type="text" id="url" value="http://" />
    <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" />
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

I used jQuery. For reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.location

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
    header("Location: " . $_GET['url']);
?>
```

should be what you need.

Comment: No. I was loading the correct page. loaded same page with @akhilesh's code. and it worked. BTW thanks for trying to help...